# Django QuerySet to return unique objects in ManyToMany fields

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

Given the following models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()

class Book(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField()
  published_year = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

Let's say I want to get all of the authors who have authored a book published in the year 2008. I can do the following:

```
Book.objects.filter(published_year=2008).values_list('authors__name').distinct()
```

That'll get me a list of authors - almost exactly what I want, except that instead of just the names, I want the Author *objects*. I can achieve that somewhat by doing this:

```
authors = []
for b in Book.objects.filter(published_year=2008):
  for a in b.authors.all():
    if a not in authors:
      authors.append(a)
```

But that seems totally unnecessary. Is it possible to get the QuerySet to do that work for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use backward relationship

```
Author.objects.filter(book__published_year=2008).all()
```

From Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

> Reverse m2m queries are supported (i.e., starting at the table that
>   doesn’t have a ManyToManyField):

Comment: In the more simple world of the example I posted, that would indeed work. My real scenario is a lot more complex, but this will work as a starting point. Thanks!

Comment: @BrettGmoser In djang docs link I posted, there are more complex examples.

Comment: The fact that Author has a book_set was the key. I've got something which does exactly what I want:

    books = Book.objects.filter(...)

    # later on
    Author.objects.filter(book_set__in=[b for b in books.all()])